# Bash: cannot break out of piped "while read" loop; process substitution works

Tags: bash, pipe

I intend to pipe the output of a program into a `while read VAR` loop and `break` when a pattern is found, but it doesn't.

Proof of concept:

```
inotifywait -qm -e create . | while read line; do echo $line; break; done
./ CREATE newfile
```

..

```
tail -f /var/log/syslog | while read line; do echo $line; break; done
Nov 6 22:44:05 section9 ntpdate[2381]: adjust time server 91.189.89.199 offset 0.272779 sec
```

These never exit no matter what the source program outputs. Setting `set -x` beforehand suggests that the loop never iterates to the second `read`. `$BASH_SUBSHELL` is 1 in these examples.

Shouldn't `tail`, `inotifywait`, etc. receive SIGPIPE and exit?

Note that process substitution (`while read ... break; done < <(tail -f ...)`) works OK. `$BASH_SUBSHELL` is 0 in this case.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The key is that, under bash (other may shells differ), a pipeline is not terminated until *all commands* in the pipeline are finished.

To understand, let's consider:

```
inotifywait -qm -e create . | while read line; do echo $line; break; done
```

When `read` reads a line, it is echoed and then `break` is executed and the last process terminates.  The first process, however, continues until a write to stdout fails.  Thus, the loop will continue at least until `inotifywait` tries to write its *second* line of output.  Because of the vagaries of buffering, it may not happen even then.  It may take several lines before the discovery occurs.  When that attempted write fails, then SIGPIPE is issued.

Now, consider the other case:

```
while read line; do echo $line; break; done < <(inotifywait -qm -e create .)
```

Here, there is no pipeline.  When `break` is executed, the `while` loop is done.

#### Documentation

From the "Pipelines" section of `man bash`:

> The shell **waits for all commands** in the pipeline to terminate....

This behavior is a choice made by `bash`.  It is not mandated by POSIX.  [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html) states:

> If the pipeline is not in the background (see Asynchronous Lists), the shell
>   shall wait for the last command specified in the pipeline to complete, **and 
>   may also wait** for all commands to complete.

Comment: "the loop will continue at least until `inotifywait` tries to write its _second_ line of output." There's the rub! SIGPIPE isn't issued when the reader process ends, but when a _write_ fails. Also, the pipe can hold a lot: `tail` manages to write some 30K without getting a broken pipe. Thanks!

Comment: I suppose `inotifywait` exits because its output is flushed on every line (I don't see any calls to `fflush`, though).

Comment: I was almost about to /wrists before coming across this answer, thought I was going crazy. Thanks OP!

Answer (score 2):

```
strace tail -f -n 5000 /var/log/messages | 
    while read line; do echo $line; break; done;
```

shows in detail what happens:

```
[...]
write(1, "Nov  1 22:20:01 inno systemd[1]:"..., 4096) = 4096
```

i.e. tail writes up to 4096 bytes at once to the pipeline (that is what a pipeline can buffer). Usually there is not so much data at all for `tail`:

```
strace tail -f /var/log/messages | while read line; do echo $line; break; done;
```

shows

```
write(1, "Nov  7 07:00:02 inno systemd[1]:"..., 730) = 730
```

Thus `tail` would not try to write again until something is appended to the file.

I thought `unbuffer` would solve this problem. I am surprised that it doesn't.

```
unbuffer tail -f file1 | while read line; do echo $line; break; done
```

Comment: The pipe can hold quite a bit when buffered - `tail` manages to write some 30K without getting a broken pipe. As John1024 said in the other answer, what I was missing is that SIGPIPE is received _when a write fails_, not when the process at the other end exits.

Comment: @arielCo Write on what level? To the kernel syscall? Not under Linux I guess. The standard libraries do their own buffering though.

Comment: yes, the calls to `write()` in Linux succeed even after the downstream/reader process is gone, until enough has been written to "jam" the pipe. For a few hundred bytes as in `tail -f`, the writer won't notice that anything went wrong on the other side of the pipe. Now in `tail -5000f /usr/share/dict/american-english`, `write()` fails with EPIPE(-1) after a few tens of KB written. And `inotifywait` is "unbuffered" so it fails trying to write the second line.