# How to use inotifywait to watch a directory for creation of files of a specific extension

Tags: shell-script, shell, filesystems, monitoring, inotify

I have seen [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24952/script-to-monitor-folder-for-new-files#answer-24955):

> You should consider using inotifywait, as an example:
>
> ```
> inotifywait -m /path -e create -e moved_to |
>     while read path action file; do
>         echo "The file '$file' appeared in directory '$path' via '$action'"
>         # do something with the file
>     done
> ```

The above script watches a directory for creation of files of any type. My question is how to modify the [`inotifywait`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/inotifywait.1.html) command to report only when a file of a certain type/extension is created (or moved into the directory). For example, it should report when any `.xml` file is created.

**What I tried**:

I have run the `inotifywait --help` command, and have read the command line options. It has `--exclude <pattern>` and `--excludei <pattern>` options to *EXCLUDE* files of certain types (by using regular expressions), but I need a way to *INCLUDE* just the files of a certain type/extension.

Comment: BTW, using `path` above is probably not the best variable name if you want to play with this first in a shell. If you use it, then you will not be able to use commands and everything since this has basically just overridden the standard `PATH`. 

Hence I recommend using an alternative var name, like `fpath` instead. i.e.
`while read fpath action file` then any standard command usually available from your shell will still be.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

> how do I modify the `inotifywait` command to report only when a file of
> certain type/extension is created

Please note that this is **untested code** since I don't have access to `inotify` right now. But something akin to this ought to work with `bash`:

```
inotifywait -m /path -e create -e moved_to |
    while read -r directory action file; do
        if [[ "$file" =~ .*xml$ ]]; then # Does the file end with .xml?
            echo "xml file" # If so, do your thing here!
        fi
    done
```

Alternatively, without `bash`,

```
inotifywait -m /path -e create -e moved_to |
    while read -r directory action file; do
        case "$file" in
            (*.xml)
                echo "xml file" # Do your thing here!
                ;;
        esac
        fi
    done
```

With newer versions of `inotifywait` you can directly create a pattern match for files:

```
inotifywait -m /path -e create -e moved_to --include '.*\.xml$' |
    while read -r directory action file; do
        echo "xml file" # Do your thing here!
    done
```

Comment: This does work and I have tested it with inotifywait.

Comment: How do you run this? Is it a one-time command, or does it need to be running in a loop or anything like that?  Perhaps as part of `incron` (I hope not).

Comment: @SDsolar It varies. For me, I usually run `inotify` either with `nohup` or start it with a custom systemd service. Most often the latter.

Comment: If the watched directory has a particularly large filed moved into it, what happens if the file transfer is not complete before the script reaches to `do your thing` action? Shouldn't one wait for a `close_write` event? Likewise, if the `do your thing` code is long-running, do the `inotifywait` events need to be queued somehow?

Comment: Avoid using *`bash regex`* which is performance killer! Prefer to use `case $file in *.xml` which is a lot lighter and quicker!! [See my answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/750965/27653) (with interactive purpose.)

Comment: `[[` is not a standard shell command.  If you use non-standard extensions, you should be clear about this when answering [tag:shell] questions.

Answer (score 14):

`--include` and `--includei` are actual options, in the master version of the binaries at least:

https://github.com/inotify-tools/inotify-tools/tree/master

Comment: Apparently, the include options are only available from version 3.20.1.

Comment: I upgraded Fedora Rawhide to the latest version and many other distros have picked up this by now in their latest versions.

Answer (score 11):

Whilst the double-negative approach of [the previous answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/382591/16359) is a nice idea since (as TMG noted) it does indeed shift the job of filtering to `inotifywait`, it is not correct.

For example, if a file ends in `as` then it will not match `[^j][^s]$` because the final letter `s` does not match `[^s]`, therefore it will not be excluded.

In Boolean terms, if `S` is the statement:

> "the final letter is `s`"

and `J` is the statement:

> "the penultimate letter is `j`"

then the value of the `--exclude` parameter should semantically equate to `not(J and S)`, which by [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) is `not(J) or not(S)`.

Another potential problem is that in `zsh`, `$path` is a built-in variable representing the array equivalent of `$PATH`, so the `while read path ...` line will completely mess up `$PATH` and cause everything to become unexecutable from the shell.

Therefore the correct approach is:

```
inotifywait -m --exclude "[^j].$|[^s]$" /path -e create -e moved_to |
    while read dir action file; do
        echo "The file '$file' appeared in directory '$dir' via '$action'"
    done
```

Note the `.` which is needed after `[^j]` to ensure that the match is applied in the penultimate position, and also that the `|` character (representing the boolean OR mentioned above) should not be escaped here because `--exclude` takes POSIX extended regular expressions.

However, please see **and upvote** @ericcurtin's [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/563905/16359) which for newer versions of `inotifywait` is a far cleaner approach.

Comment: What if your code is C code and you want to include .c and .h files

Comment: `--exclude '[^ch]$|[^.].$'` should achieve that (although I haven't tested).

Answer (score 11):

**Starting with inotifywait version 3.20.1** you can use an `--include` option.

## inotifywait example with `--include`

Here's an example that uses `--include` to run a script when a wav file is added to a directory.

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

# Usage
#
# Call the script with the directory you want to watch as an argument. e.g.:
# watchdir.sh /app/foo/
#
#
# Description:
# Uses inotifywait to look for new files in a directory and process them:
# inotifywait outputs data which is passed (piped) to a do for subcommands.
#
#
# Requirements:
# Requires inotifywait which is part of inotify-tools.
# e.g. yum install -y inotify-tools or apt-get install -y inotify-tools.
#
#
# See also:
# https://linux.die.net/man/1/inotifywait
# https://github.com/inotify-tools/inotify-tools/wiki#info
# (Might be interested in pyinotify too.)


echo "Watch $1 for file changes..."


# Be careful not to confuse the output of `inotifywait` with that of `echo`.
# e.g. missing a `\` would break the pipe and write inotifywait's output, not
# the echo's.
inotifywait \
  $1 \
  --monitor \
  -e create \
  --timefmt '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S' \
  --format '%T %w %f %e' \
  --include "\.wav" \
| while read datetime dir filename event; do
  echo "Event: $datetime $dir$file $event"
  echo "Now, we could pass $datetime $dir $filename and $event to some other command."

  echo "Here's the extensionless filename:" ${filename%.*}
  echo "And the extension if needed:" ${filename##*.}

  python3 /app/phono.py --custom $dir$filename $dir${filename%.*}.txt /tmp/${filename%.*}
done


# --format:
#   %T  Replaced with the current Time in the format specified by the --timefmt option, which should be a format string suitable for passing to strftime(3).
#   %w  This will be replaced with the name of the Watched file on which an event occurred.
#   %f  When an event occurs within a directory, this will be replaced with the name of the File which caused the event to occur. Otherwise, this will be replaced with an empty string.
#   %e  Replaced with the Event(s) which occurred, comma-separated.
#   %Xe Replaced with the Event(s) which occurred, separated by whichever character is in the place of 'X'.
#
# There's no --include option, but there's --exclude, which can be used to the same effect as an include.


# test the script by creating a file in the watched directory, e.g.
# touch /app/foo/file1.wav # will trigger the script
# touch /app/foo/file1.txt # will not trigger the script
```

## Installing (or compiling) inotify-tools

inotifywait is part of inotify-tools. You can install it via the usual way, e.g.:

```
apt-get install -y inotify-tools
```

or

```
yum install -y inotify-tools
```

But if only older versions are available from the repos, you may want to compile from source. If so:

```bsh
cd /tmp/inotify-tools/
wget https://github.com/inotify-tools/inotify-tools/releases/download/3.20.2.2/inotify-tools-3.20.2.2.tar.gz
tar xzvf inotify-tools-3.20.2.2.tar.gz
cd inotify-tools-3.20.2.2
./configure --prefix=/usr --libdir=/lib64
make
make install
```

Answer (score 10):

Use a double negative:

```
inotifywait -m --exclude "[^j][^s]$" /path -e create -e moved_to |
    while read path action file; do
        echo "The file '$file' appeared in directory '$path' via '$action'"
    done
```

This will only include javascript files

Comment: Nice, I like that it shifts the filtering to `inotifywait` rather than have it generate huge output for all files and filter afterwards (like in the other answer). Haven't tried, but I guess that would perform a bit faster.

Comment: This is just what I was looking for. How to modify the `--exclude` input to watch for `.ext` files. This is run only once or in a for loop?

Comment: It's a daemon, so it will run until it crashes or you shut it down :)

Comment: Sorry, missed the first question.

`inotifywait -m --exclude "[^.][^e][^x][^t]$" /home/jonas/Skrivbord/test -e create -e moved_to |
    while read path action file; do
        echo "The file '$file' appeared in directory '$path' via '$action'"
    done`

I'm sure the regex can be optimized, but this baby works :)

Comment: Thanxs!! I'll try it out!!

Comment: Hello, i'm trying to watch for two types of files in the same directory `txt` and `torrent`. I put two `inotifywait` services running, each for each kind of file, but both recognize both files changes.

Comment: True. For some reason the [^.] doesn't work. (Regex is a bitch imho)

Just skip it.

Comment: Thanks for the nice idea, but unfortunately it's flawed. I have posted [a follow-up answer with corrections](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/477708/16359).

Comment: As @AdamSpiers notes, this answer is incorrect, because it would trigger on any file ending in jX or Xs (.ja, .jb, .jc… ..as, .bs. .cs…)

Answer (score 1):

The best solutions are the ones that suggest using `inotifywait`'s built in `--include` and `--includei` (**from version 3.20.1**).

Notice there is a **bug** with `--include` and `--includei` that result in relevant files being ignored when new directories are created while `inotifywait` is watching the parent directory. See the open [Github issue](https://github.com/inotify-tools/inotify-tools/issues/168). At the time of writing, version 3.22.6.0 has this bug.

A workaround is to validate the filename in the loop.

```
inotifywait \
  <DIRECTORY_TO_WATCH> \
  --monitor \
  --recursive \
  -e create \
  --timefmt '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S' \
  --format '%T %w %f %e' \
| while read datetime dir filename event; do
  # if the file does not include .xml then continue the loop
  ! [[ "$filename" =~ \.xml ]] && continue

  # otherwise the file includes .xml and we do something with it
  echo "Event: $datetime $dir$file $event"
done
```

This is not optimal, but the best solution if you will have directories being dynamically created while `inotifywait` is watching the parent directory.

Comment: You might want to also watch `moved_to` names - that certainly helped me recently with some `dev` files that get created with a temporary name and only get their final name once written.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was trying to filter the output of `inotifywait` using something like grep, in order to wait for the creation of a single file with a particular extension. The trouble with this approach is that grep will just hang.

For some reason a SIGPIPE signal is either not sent, or not processed by `inotifywait`. I found [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/166546/382524) question, which ran into the same issue I had, and process substitution can be used as a workaround:

`grep -E .*iso -m1 < <(inotifywait -qm -e create .)`

Process substitution does not work in certain shells (eg. `sh`), so this does not work in every case.

---

From the other answers given, I could not find the --include option. I will likely be experimenting with --exclude.

Comment: If your version doesn't have `--include`, it's too old and you should see if you can upgrade since if you can that will be the easiest solution by far.

Comment: I downloaded a brand new version, which doesn't have it. I see `--include` now in the source code though. I was originally looking at https://github.com/inotify-tools/inotify-tools/blob/master/man/inotifywatch.1.in , which does not mention `--include` in the same way it mentions `--exclude`.

Comment: According to [another answer on this page](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/606213/16359), you need at least 3.20.1.

Answer (score 0):

## `bash` interactive script monitor using `inotifywait`:

As all answer here address `inotifywait -m | script`, I would like to suggest another way to waiting for input...

### Basically:

```
while read path action file; do
    printf 'XML File: %s/%s\n' "$path" "$file"
done < <(inotifywait -me close_write,moved_to --include '.*\.xml$' /path)
```

- Having *main script* reading input from redirected sub -process is easier to understand mostly about global variables en further script.
- Using *close-write* event ensure you file won't be modified at time your script will work on.

### Interactive script

- Use another *File descriptor* for `inotifywait` will let you use *STDIN* for other interactions:

  ```
  exec {inotimon}< <(exec inotifywait -m /tmp/so -e close_write 2>&1)
  ```

  This will run `inotifywait` in background and redirect both *`STDOUT`* and *`STDERR`* to a new *file descriptor*, then store file descriptor's  *value* to `$inotimon` variable.
- Use `trap`, `kill` and `USR2` signal for avoiding pool on two inputs, so we run a simple `read -rsn 1 char` in background, then send character (with a *newline*) to a *new descriptor* (`$userOut`) and use `kill -USR2` to interrupt *main script*.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

declare -i countXml=0
treatXml() {
    printf 'XML File: %s/%s\n' "$1" "$2"
    countXml+=1
}
showStat() {
    printf 'There is %d files treated.\n' $countXml
}
userInput() {
    while IFS= read -d '' -rsn 1 char; do
        printf %q\\n "$char"
        kill -USR2 $1
    done
}
trapUI() {
    read -ru $userOut userKeyVal
    case ${userKeyVal,,} in
        s|*\\t* ) showStat ;;   # Keys ``s'' or ``Tab'' will show stats
        q|*\\e* ) exit ;;       # Keys ``q'' or ``Esc'' will quit.
    esac
}
```

```bash
exec {userOut}< <(userInput $$)
uipid=$!
exec {inotimon}< <(
    exec inotifywait -me close_write,moved_to --include '.*\.xml$' /tmp/so 2>&1)
inotipid=$!
closeAll() {
    exec {inotimon}<&-
    exec {userOut}<&-
    kill $uipid $inotipid
}
trap trapUI USR2
trap closeAll 0 1 2 3 6 15
while read -ru $inotimon path action file; do
    case $action in
        CLOSE*|MOVED* ) treatXml "(${action,,}) $path" "$file";;
        e* ) printf 'FD %d: %s\n' $inotimon "${path^^} ${action^^}" ;;
    esac
done
```