# Monitor several directories for specific files' creation, every 10s

Tags: linux, monitoring, inotify

OS: Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.
Many posts deal with file monitoring. [One](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/323901/how-to-use-inotifywait-to-watch-a-directory-for-creation-of-files-of-a-specific) in particular is of interest and based on `inotifywait`, but I don't know how to modify it for my purpose.

**Objective**: to monitor `$HOME/{Documents/,Downloads/,Archive/}` for link files `*.lnk` as they are created. Those files are created every time I use Word in Wine to create, save, open or do anything with a document. Dozens `*.lnk` files can be created in mere minutes. This issue is killing me.

I am willing to learn but can't translate generic examples into what I need for lack of knowledge. I know how to run a script in a plain file, but if there's anything special I should know in this regard, please let me know. Tx in advance.

Comment: Are the `.lnk` files doing any immediate harm ? If they can be left around for (e.g.) five minutes, I would probably solve this with a simple `cron` job, rather than trigger an inotify and rm process for every individual file and each directory, which I suspect uses more resources per file.

Comment: @Paul_Pedant, you have a point. Could be using `-r`option on `/home/$USER` but it may not be very efficient.

Comment: The .lnk files quickly overtake my workspace (which are my folders I'm working in), switching between docs, etc, there are dozens of them, so yes, they're negatively affecting my ability to work quickly and efficiently. Fixing this is more important to me than using resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write this small script in a file using your terminal. I assume you are using the `bash` shell since you are beginning, and on Ubuntu. Let us know if it is otherwise.

```
$ touch notify_links
$ chmod u+x notify_links
$ cat notify_script
#!/usr/bin/env bash
inotifywait -mr -e moved_to,create "$HOME"/{Documents,Downloads,Archive} |
while read directory action file; do
    if [[ "$file" =~ .lnk$ ]]; then
        echo rm -f "$file"
    fi
done
```

Run this script. To do so, just issue (in terminal) the following command `notify_links` in terminal.

Once satisfied by what you see appearing on terminal display, remove the `echo` in the script line: `echo rm -f "$file"` to leave only `rm -f "$file"`.

**EDIT 1** per @ilkkachu's comment in order to specialize monitoring to three directories/folders instead of the complete `$HOME` subtree.

**EDIT 2** per @Paul_Pedant's comment, in order to run this automatically every 10 seconds as soon as your boot process is finished, edit your `/etc/crontab` file with `crontab -e` to include:

```
 * * * * * $USER for i in $(seq 5); do /usr/bin/find $HOME -name "*.lnk" -delete; sleep 10; done
```

**EDIT 3** for faster result and lesser resource usage, you'll want to search only the directories that you mentionned in OP. The following will search their subtrees:

```
 * * * * * $USER for i in $(seq 5); do /usr/bin/find "$HOME"/{Documents,Downloads,Archive} -name "*.lnk" -delete; sleep 10; done
```

In order to prevent `find` from recursing down the subtrees, add the following option `-maxdepth 1` *before* `-name "*.lnk"` in the `find` command.

Comment: Does this require three separate scripts, for Documents, Downloads and Archives, as noted in the question ?

Comment: I figured it out (bin bash file) and it worked for the one folder, thanks, though I have multiple folders. But I'd prefer a background process that doesn't involve an open terminal to run, or my having to run scripts manually. That's why I was looking for inotifywait to run in the background whenever I boot. To educate myself is there a reason inotifywait is bad to use for this? Because someone already did the work in the hyperlink posted in the OP, for someone else asking the same exact thing, but I don't know how to modify the code there. –

Comment: @Paul_Pedant, `inotifywait -r` would recursively set watches on all directories in the tree, and the script here gives the path `/home/$USER` to `inotifywait`. (That should probably be just `$HOME`, though.) Of course one could change that to `inotifywait -m -e moved_to,create "$HOME"/{Documents,Downloads,Archive}` to just include those three.

Comment: @Trynn, well, starting a script in the background automatically is a bit of a different question. One way would be to use an `@reboot` rule with cron. There are others and some of them would require making sure you don't run two copies of the same script at the same time. And yes, of course you could just put `* * * * * find ~ -name '*.lnk' -delete` in crontab. (At least as long as there' aren't directories within your home where those .lnk-files should _not_ be deleted.

Comment: This is what I'm looking for, so maybe a cron job instead. I will do more research on that now, but no, there are no folders anywhere where I want or need .lnk files! So covering the entire tree at boot would be ideal.

Comment: Only thing is, just read about cron jobs and it sounds like they run every minute at most... can it be set to watch for the creation of a link file and immediately delete it like your script did? In one minute dozens of .lnk files are created.

Comment: @Cbhihe, or just run `crontab -e` under their regular user account. And actually the syntax of `/etc/crontab` and the files in `/etc/cron.d/*` is different from what I just wrote: the system-wide files have an additional column for the username to run under. (It's an additional column, not a replacement to the last `*`)

Comment: @Trynn, no, `cron` runs tasks based on the time, on a fixed schedule. It doesn't do what e.g. `inotifywait` or other such tools do.

Comment: Thanks, but between that question and now, I learned it won't delete files on the fly as they're created, so a cron won't work. I need something that catches the files as they are created. I found FileWatcher yesterday which had an XML template and tried using that but again I got some character wrong and it didn't execute the task.

Comment: I understand, and your script did what I wanted, so that's what I meant. I thought inotifywait would perform this function in the background at boot, basically doing what your script did, but without having to manually run it or have a terminal open. I apologize for my ignorance and can see I need to do much more research before asking for help. Thanks for your time and your help AND for modifying your script! I will mark your answer as solved. Cheers.

Comment: @Trynn  You can write a trivial script under `cron` which runs the rm on entry, with a loop that also runs 5 times after `sleep 10` (for example). That gives you a 10-second delay. I am concerned that `inotify` monitors the whole sub-directory tree under the nominated start points, but then I suspect this requirement was implied in your question (I didn't pick up on that).

Comment: @Cbhihe Thank you for that last comment and the suggestions. Will do a deep-dive into that tremendously helpful guidance. If needed will ask a new question after self-ed and trials. Sincerely appreciated your time and patience in this ramp-up into Linux.

Comment: @Paul_Pendant Very good to know, thank you. Everything I'm learning will definitely come in handy!

Comment: @Cbhihe - you were editing the script as I was leaving a comment to you. Thank you once again!

Comment: @Cbhihe - those last edits were brilliant - can't thank you and Paul enough, and ilkkachu too ... so appreciated!

Comment: @Paul_Pedant, if one doesn't want `inotifywait` to set watches to the whole subtree, they can leave the `-r` option out.

Comment: @ilkkachu I will try the script with the three folders first (after I read more about all of this) but then I do want the Home tree covered as I will be using Word in new folders I create as time goes on (and in others already there). So I will be switching that line to leaving just "$HOME" after trials. And thank you for your help here!

Comment: Have the old script too, the correct line is not what I wrote above but the following, just so you know I have it right.    inotifywait -mr -e moved_to,create /home/$USER |