# Pipe from a while loop to a command but execute another command if pipe command fails

Tags: bash, debian

Environment:  armv7l GNU/Linux Debian Jessie,  GNU `bash`, *v4.3.30(1)-release (arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf)*.

- `do_stuff`: a long running process which generates output to STDOUT
- `compare_output.pl`: a `perl` script which does things based on the output.

I want to be able to restart the `compare_output.pl` in case the process `compare_output.pl` breaks (dies).
Even a simple `echo` after the `while` loop, (and after the `compare_output.pl`), was unsuccessful.

Sadly I lack the idea how to actually do this in `bash`.
Bonus for retaining the Cache/Puffer of the `do_stuff` process.

```
while true;
do
  ...
  do_stuff (which generates lot of output linewise to STDOUT)
  ...
done | compare_output.pl 
#then something like this should happen, while retaining 
#the while loop and being able to "reattach" to the pipe.
"compare_output died? restart it "
```

Sometimes `compare_output.pl` breaks, (dies actually), which loses the whole pipe input.  (Needless to say `compare_output.pl` should not break, but that is another problem for another day).

When `compare_output` breaks I want to be able to reuse the while loop, to be able to reattach to the pipe output. Losing one or a few lines is acceptable.

I tried using command substitution instead of a pipe:

```
while true;
do
  ...
  do_stuff (which generates lot of output linewise)
  ...
done < <( compare_output.pl )
# then something like this should happen, while retaining
# the while loop and being able to "reattach" to the pipe.
compare_output died? restart it "
```

`restart_while_loop` in case `compare_output.pl` fails (dies)

read and adapted from 
[Bash: cannot break out of piped "while read" loop; process substitution works](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/166546/bash-cannot-break-out-of-piped-while-read-loop-process-substitution-works)

This other than obstructing output seems to not resolve my issue that I want to act after `compare_output.pl` dies.

When I did *CTRL-C* then my `echo test` gets executed, which i did instead of the `compare_output.pl restart test`.

Otherwise `do_stuff` still runs for a long time.

Other than that I did read about piping and process substitution, lots of questions here but I seem to lack the right keyword to search for.

I know of
[Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice)
and understand that the way I do it is bad practice, but it's the situation I'm in which I currently cannot change.

So how can I get something to happen as soon as possible after `compare_output.pl` dies? (process stops running, no `ps` entry)

I am open for a full rewrite of the loop if that should be the only option to get this actually working. Currently I do not want to use other scripting languages, but if necessary I (somehow) could rewrite this in `perl` but would like not to.

Comment: It's not clear what this code is meant to do.   After `compare_output.pl` dies, is the goal to run `echo test` or restart the `while` loop?

Comment: the plan is to restart the loop, sorry, i will edit this, i was under the impression that this are basically 2 issues i am having which i wanted to split down to not ask 2 questions in one.

Comment: It seems to me you want to restart `compare_output.pl` if it breaks, and not the loop (which can be allowed to continue) ... which is what Jeff's answer suggests!

Comment: after further evaluation you are right muru that the question suggests the while loop restart, while Jeff is actually more of what the code really should do.
I will reword the whole question to actually show that the compare_output.pl should restart, not the whole "while do_stuff loop"

Comment: Re *"more of what the code really should do"*: please be more specific, does [*Jeff Schaller*'s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/438778/165517) solve the  problem or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pipe the first loop into another loop:

```
while :; do ./do_stuff ; done | 
  while :; do ./compare_output.pl ; done
```